# Group by similar dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, data-analysis

I have a dataframe that has one column which is a datetime series object. It has some data associated with every date in another column. The year ranges from 2005-2014. I want to group similar dates in each year together, i.e, all the 1st January falling in 2005-15 must be grouped together irrespective of the year.Similarly for all the 365 days in a year. So I should have 365 days as the output. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: ID Date Element Data_Value
0 USW00094889 2014-11-12 TMAX 22
1 USC00208972 2009-04-29 TMIN 56
2 USC00200032 2008-05-26 TMAX 278
3 USC00205563 2005-11-11 TMAX 139
4 USC00200230 2014-02-27 TMAX -106
5 USW00014833 2010-10-01 TMAX 194
6 USC00207308 2010-06-29 TMIN 144

Comment: It is something like this. I don't find an option to attach photos in the comment. This dataframe has ID, Date, Element and Data_Value column for a particular vicinity.

Comment: please write it in your post with the proper line spacements

Comment: @GarethMa: Please do not advise to use pastebin when adding **text** to the post is enough.

Comment: You can `groupby` on a `Series` sharing the dataframe index. So it could look like `df.groupby([d.dt.month, d.dt.mday].agg(...)`. Please show some data *in the question itself* if you need more.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/1BpcNufp

Comment: For all the people attempting to help, this is the data he shared: (Yes I typed manually): `d = {'ID': ['USW00094889', 'USC00208972', 'USC00200032', 'USC00205563', 'USC00200230', 'USW00014833', 'USC00207308'],
     'Date': ['2014-11-12', '2009-04-29', '2008-05-26', '2005-11-11', '2014-02-27', '2010-10-01', '2010-06-29'],
     'Element': ['TMAX', 'TMIN', 'TMAX', 'TMAX', 'TMAX', 'TMAX', 'TMIN'],
     'Data_Value': [22, 56, 278, 139, -106, 194,144]}; df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame has a column `Date`, you can make it the index of the DataFrame and then use `strftime`, to convert to a format with only day and month (like `"%m-%d"`), and `groupby` plus the appropriate function (I just used `mean`):

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.index = df.index.strftime("%m-%d")
dfAggregated = df.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Please note that the output will have 366 days, due to leap years. You might want to filter out the data associated to Feb 29th or merge it into Feb 28th/March 1st (depending on the specific use case of your application)

Comment: This error throws up when I use strftime method - AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: looks like the `Date` column doesn't have a `datetime64` type (as stated in your question). Try using `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` before calling `strftime`

Comment: the Date column was actually an object type but I had converted it to datetime64 type before calling this method.